# What Operating System does the DCP 2000 use?

Tags: film-industry

I recently watched a movie in an empty theater. When the credits started rolling, I wandered to the projection room and asked the operator if there was an after-credit scene. He was using a server that looks almost like rack servers one sees in datacenters with hot swappable HDD. It was called **DCP 2000** and had a screen with a Windows-like operating system.

Going online, I didn't find much information since the manufacturing company was absorbed by **Dolby**. So what's the operating system and by extension the file system used?

Comment: Servers usually use various Linux distributions, perhaps Ubuntu's most popular. The file system would be likely ext4.

Comment: ‘Windows-like’. Almost all desktop environments are ‘Windows-like’. macOS and it’s ancestors (and clones) are really the only major exception to this unless you count single-purpose kiosk systems or decide that having a different panel (task bar) layout makes it not ‘Windows-like’.

Comment: re  "I've recently watched a movie in an empty theater ..." --> Schroedingers patron :-).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of August 2014, the most recently mentioned [supported Operating System](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/29384561/dcp-2000-and-dcp-2k4-field-installer-manual-doremi-labs) for the DCP-2000 is Linux.

"*Debian 4.0*" and "*Linux kernel 2.6.22.6*" are mentioned in various documents relating to the 2000 series projector. Other projectors in the same stable use more recent versions of "*Red Hat Enterprise Linux*" (RHEL).

> This release installs a new Linux kernel. This kernel supports PCIe
> hot plug event ONLY on units fitted with SuperMicro motherboard (with
> the latest DCP-2000 operating system - Debian 4.0).
>
> <sub><sup>[Software Release Notes](https://smart-story.ru/files/products/multimedia/mediaplayers/Dolby/Dolby_ShowVault-IMB2K4/firmware/sw/DCP2000_Software_Release_Notes_000288_v4_6_sw2-6-3.pdf)</sup></sub>

and

> 9.7.3 Known Issues: There is no known issue referenced at this time.
>
> 9.7.4 System Changes: Upgrade to Linux kernel 2.6.22.6.
>
> 9.7.5 Compatibility Notes: The release is fully compatible with other 0.5.2-x releases.
>
> <sub><sup>[DCP-2000 / Software Release Notes](https://smart-story.ru/files/products/multimedia/mediaplayers/Dolby/Dolby_ShowVault-IMB2K4/firmware/sw/DCP2000_Software_Release_Notes_000288_v4_6_sw2-6-3.pdf)</sup></sub>

---

The front-end system you were looking at was probably a custom User Interface developed for that projector called [Doremi WebGUI](https://vimeo.com/162303948) / or [Doremi ShowVault](https://smart-story.ru/files/products/multimedia/mediaplayers/Dolby/Dolby_ShowVault-IMB2K4/Docs/Dolby_Doremi_ShowVault_User_Manual_001663_v1_7.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately the release note links don't work for me.  I wonder how accurate the Debian 4.0 is ... since that is from 2007.  It's not inconceivable that a nearly 20 year old release is still the basis for a device OS, but it is surprising.

Comment: @iandotkelly - I'm just trying to track down the current release notes. Like a lot of manuals, they don't seem to be for public consumption, but I think we can be reasonably assured that the answer is still some flavour of Linux.

Comment: For sure, and Debian represents a huge family of Linux distributions.

Comment: @iandotkelly For the type of device involved, Debian 4.x is not that strange or surprising. The systems in question are low-value for anything but DoS attacks, likely don’t have internet access, and may not even be networked. That’s about as low priority to upgrade as you can find as long as everything is working.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn ... also when I look for the model, I can see youtube video's from 2010 about it.

Comment: @iandotkelly The basic aspects of Digital Cinema are based on technologies that were created way more than 20 years ago. For instance, frames are individually stored using the JPEG 2000 format, released in 2000. Audio tracks are either based on "old" standards like AC-3 (aka "Dolby Digital", 1991) if not even uncompressed audio ("Broadcast Wave Format", using the "WAV" format, also 1991), or eventually stored as "streams" for more modern systems (like ATMOS) that can be eventually "read" by the server or sent to a dedicated decoder. Such servers are fundamentally very simple, as they only »

Comment: @iandotkelly » have to do just a few things, and *nothing more*: manage stored data, send decoded frames to projectors, decode/send audio data, and provide a user interface for all that. They don't have to be "modern" computers, but fast and reliable ones. No need to support fancy graphics or animations, or audio/video compression to optimize low network speeds, nor anything a current end-user device would need for everyday usage, including web access (which involves *lots* of security related updates). A 2007 Linux OS is certainly more than capable of that, in a very reliable and secure way.

Comment: I understand that 2007 Linux is capable, my initial surprise (before I found the model was from 2010) was just that the version of the OS was quite old - just from a point of view of obtaining support and documentation, as well as security.